# Automapper and MvcPager3 working together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I want to add Pagination to one of my views using MvcPager3. This would be simple, except that I'm already using AutoMapper to map my model to a simplied viewmodel.

```
        List<Call> calls = (from p in db.Calls orderby p.ID descending select p).ToList();

        var viewModel = new List<CallListItem>();

        Mapper.Map(calls, viewModel);

        return View(viewModel);
```

I thought it might be as simple as replacing this line

```
var viewModel = new List<CallListItem>();
```

with this

```
var viewModel = new PagedList<CallListItem>();
```

But PagedList has a constructor which takes a list of items. Since automapper is going to be doing this for me I thought I might be able to pass null, but it doesn't work.

Anybody have experience with using these two components in harmony?

Thanks

Edit:

Found an alternative to MvcPager called PagedList. It's much better because it has a StaticPagedList class which you can use for data which has already been paged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could paginate the view model after the mapping:

```
var calls = (from p in db.Calls orderby p.ID descending select p).ToList();
var viewModel = Mapper
    .Map<IEnumerable<Call>, IEnumerable<CallListItem>>(calls)
    .ToPagedList(currentPage, pageSize);
return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes the paged elements will be a member on another viewmodel, eg.. MyViewModel.SomePagedElements, I would like Automapper to be able to handle these situations also, without manual intervention.

Comment: @NoPyGod, so you basically want AutoMapper to be knowing about the `currentPage` and the `pageSize` in addition to the source type? AutoMapper is not intended to be used that way. It maps between a single source type and a single destination type.

Comment: With automapper2, you don't need the generic source type arg -- only the generic target type arg, i.e. `Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CallListItem>>(calls)`

Comment: This response is not the right one. It won't paginate in the database server. See @Alvis response.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can paginate first and map afterwards by using StaticPagedList. 
This worked for me:

```
var calls = (from p in db.Calls orderby p.ID descending select p).ToPagedList();
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CallListItem>>(calls);
return new StaticPagedList<CallListItem>(viewModel, calls);
```

I did this because I did not want to list all the objects in order to page later.

Based on this nice [post](http://michele.berto.li/using-automapper-with-pagedlist/).

Comment: You don't need the GetMetatada. just pass calls

Comment: Thanks, @regisbsb, I have updated the answer (although not tested myself).

Comment: Should update the Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Call>> to Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CallListItem>> as well, I believe the return type is on Automapper and the incomming is infered.